# dynamic content not updating in list Swift UI

Tags: listview, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I am having real trouble here.
I have a list that I am trying to add a new item to the list each time I add a new line of data to my data file however it is just showing the same data.

I have scoured the internet and even tried following the apple developer site.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plDKa.png)

[List Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvix7.png)

[List View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csLdn.png)

Comment: you should share text. Not image. We can not copy-paste

Comment: As said it's better if you share text instead of photos. Anyway, it is always showing the same item because in ListItem you are initializing it with item[0]. On the ListView 's ForEach loop you have to pass the item to the ListView constructor and use it instead of the item[0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct ListItem: View {
     var item: VocabItem
      ...  
}

struct VocabList {
     .
     .
     .
       
       ForEach(items) { item in
           ListItem(item: item)
       }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely awesome, thank you. I was missing the (item: item)